# the keyboard doesn't move the components up in the Emulator

Tags: android, keyboard

the keyboard doesn't move the components up in Android Emulator
I'm using Nexus 5X API 26(Android 8.0.0, API 26)

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.seung.chatapp2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>


`activity_main.xml`



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="549dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pswdEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pswdText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LoginBtn"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:text="login"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:text="SIgn up"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

when I runned the app on my emulator before setting the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`, the components still weren't moved up by keayboard.

and then I found that `InputMode`. but they aren't moved up still.

I am using Nexus 5X API 26(Android 8.0.0, API 26).

Answer (score 0):

try this in your manifest.xml

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```